# Can't start gulp on Vagrant VM (Ubuntu, precise64)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, gulp

Using Vagrant VM. I have a project with the following `devDependencies` in `package.json`:

```
"gulp": "^3.8.0",
"gulp-clean": "^0.2.4",
"gulp-load-plugins": "^0.5.0"
```

And the `gulpfile.js`:

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('clean', function () {
});
```

I have installed them with `npm install` command. I have installed gulp with `npm install gulp -g` as well.

When I try to run any gulp command (for example `gulp -T`), I get the following result:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'lodash._createwrapper'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/api/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob2base/node_modules/lodash.findindex/node_modules/lodash.createcallback/node_modules/lodash._basecreatecallback/node_modules/lodash.bind/index.js:9:21)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/api/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob2base/node_modules/lodash.findindex/node_modules/lodash.createcallback/node_modules/lodash._basecreatecallback/index.js:9:12)
```

After I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24144479/878514) and added `lodash.bind` to my project dependencies, gulp does not work either, but then the exception says that it can't find module `lodash.identity`.

What may cause these problems? VM is [precise64](https://vagrantcloud.com/hashicorp/precise64), Debian 3.2.57-3. Gulp 3.8.2, Node v0.10.28.

Comment: I have no clue what the issue is, but this PR in glob2base will likely fix it since it doesn't depend on lodash.findindex anymore: https://github.com/wearefractal/glob2base/pull/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by long path Windows restrictions (as described [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1953)). Running `npm isntall && gulp` on Windows host machine works as expected and without the described error.

However, such configuration would be very difficult to maintain if some commands needs to be run on host and some on guest Vagrant machine. So, for now, my long-term solution is to give up with Vagrant at all.

---

The suggestion of this solution was originally posted by @MaartenScholz, but the answer was removed before I was able to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution should anybody come across this.   There is probably a faster way, but this way works reliably (I have had to do this twice).

When you get the first error, it will say *such and such lodash package is missing*.  Install that package with npm locally using `--save-dev`.  Then run `gulp` or `gulp {your task}`, you will get a new error with a different lodash package missing.  Do this 20 or 30 times and then it will work.

Each time you are installing the missing lodash package, it then generates a new error with the another missing package.  You can short circuit this process a little bit if you look at the path of where the missing files are, you will see directories all named `lodash`.x.  If you install those `lodash`.x packages with `--save-dev`, you probably will not have to run `npm` so many times (can't verify one way or another).

**Note**:  This is hardly a proper solution, but when building a website that I needed to get done that was relying on `gulp` and `gulp-preprocess`, it became essential just to get it running.

**Comment**: A logical explanation for why this works can be found at [ [Installation of gulp through node.js's npm breaks windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143195/installation-of-gulp-through-node-jss-npm-breaks-windows?lq=1) ]

Comment: This is asinine and stupid as hell. But this is working. smh.

Comment: Just imagine how many other things I tried before it came to the point of trying that.